# HTML5 pause a video at certain points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a video and I would like to pause it at a couple different points depending on the current time of the video. There will be 3 stops, one at 5 seconds, one at 10 seconds and one at 15 seconds. At each stop, a button comes up to continue playing the video. I am not sure how to make this work because `currentTime` never hits these points exactly, so currently I have to use `>=` the time stops, which means that the 5 second stop point will continuously fire.

```js
var video = $('#video').get(0);

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(this.currentTime >= 5) {
        console.log('5 seconds');
        this.pause();
        $('button').css('display','block');
    }
    
    if(this.currentTime >= 10) {
      console.log('10 seconds');
      this.pause();
      $('button').text('Part 3');
      $('button').css('display','block');
    }
    
    if(this.currentTime >= 15) {
      console.log('15 seconds');
      this.pause();
      $('button').text('Part 4');
      $('button').css('display','block');
    }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  video.play();
  $('button').css('display','none');
});
```

```css
button {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>

<button>Part 2</button>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put ads on your video?

Comment: No, I just want to add some details to the page regarding each segment of the video and pause the video to allow the user to look over those details before continuing to the next segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've seen the `timeupdate` is not always at the *exact* interval. It can be several milliseconds out.

To fix the issue you have, you can store a variable which holds the last point in the video a `timeupdate` happened and include that in your `if` conditions:

```js
var $video = $('#video');
var video = $video.get(0);

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var lastCheckedAt = $video.data('lastcheck') || 0;
  $video.data('lastcheck', this.currentTime);
  
  if (this.currentTime >= 5 && lastCheckedAt < 5) {
    console.log('5 seconds');
    this.pause();
    $('button').show();
  } else if (this.currentTime >= 10 && lastCheckedAt < 10) {
    console.log('10 seconds');
    this.pause();
    $('button').text('Part 3').show();
  } else if (this.currentTime >= 15 && lastCheckedAt < 15) {
    console.log('15 seconds');
    this.pause();
    $('button').text('Part 4').show();
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  video.play();
  $('button').hide();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>

<button>Part 2</button>
```

Also note the use of `show()` and `hide()` instead of calling `css()` directly.

Comment: Very cool, thank you for the solution, it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I also just edited with another couple of tweaks to the logic.